# Keyboard short-cut to duplicate a line

Tags: keyboard

Is there a built-in keyboard short-cut to duplicate a line in Mathematica?
If not, is it possible to create such a short-cut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> duplicates the input cell just above the insertion point

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> duplicates the output cell just above the insertion point